# How many bolted faults can a residential circuit breaker withstand?

Tags: electrical-panel

A friend told me I should change my 20 amp breaker after one bolted fault. Is this necessary? During testing of the tread mill that caused the breaker to trip it has successfully tripped two more times so I'm suspicious of my friend's advice.

Comment: Does your friend own stock in fuses, or work for a fuse manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

How many licks does it take to get to the center of a tootsie pop is rather unanswerable. How many faults are they built to withstand and still be functional, should I swap them out after X # of faults, and are they more likely to fail-*dangerous* if they're old and abused?

---

According to the UL, *a breaker must safely clear its maximum current **twice and still be functional***. This is a manufacturing standard; not really your concern unless yours broke after the first fault.

**CBs are built to always *fail-safe*.** An older breaker that seems to nuisance trip more often than it should might be grounds for replacement and it's probably the easiest way to see if there is something funny going on but **there's no reason to arbitrarily replace them after a few faults**. Several thousand faults? you'd better check what's going on and that breaker goes in the garbage on principle.

I'm unaware of any UL testing that seeks to show a reset count limit. I'd assume the possibility of a *fail-on state* is negligible or it wouldn't be UL'ed. IME, **when they break they just don't reset anymore**. - Find me an un-safe one and we'll go sue 'em for all they've got.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking your friend is correct circuit breakers are only rated for 1 fault.
However If they were changed this often I think everyone would go back to fuses as they are cheaper. 
I have seen breakers trip 50-60 times over a few years on equipment and thought I should load test them.
Of the few I have tested they were all within 3% of their rated value. All have been slightly lower than the rating.
I decided to check some new ones just to see and used a common square D QO 20A 120V breaker on my load test station.
The first 10 trips were within 1% I faulted the breaker a total of 100 times and it was still within 2% (low).
I can tell you on higher power equipment when the breaker opens under load it causes damage to the hammer and contacts as the arc burns them slightly each time but with 120/240 breakers used in a house I have not observed the kind of damage a 480V 3 phase breaker receives. I would not change a breaker unless it becomes problematic and this is usually caused by multiple loads on the same circuit more than a weak breaker in my experience.
Note my load test was a restive oil bath load and a fluke recording amp meter that was in certified / calibrated just a month prior to the test.

Comment: [This document from Eaton](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.eaton.com/ecm/idcplg%3FIdcService%3DGET_FILE%26dID%3D203423&ved=0ahUKEwjD85GngPHKAhWNth4KHU3iCxcQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNEE_8hRiUtrdKULuY96VCxJNpmhTg&sig2=6yrYaHMyx0mFKUGDai5wDQ) states "*UL489, requires that a breaker must safely clear its maximum current, which is the short circuit current rating of the breaker, twice and still be functional.*". Which means UL requires the breaker to be able to clear at least 3 faults.

Comment: At the same time this in NO way suggest the breaker must or should be replaced after three faults.

Answer (score -1):

Most bkr mfg's recomend changing the breaker after a fault as the resistance on the contacts is slightly degraded when it trips under load or if fully loaded and someone opened the breaker same or close to the same damage, as I said most house hold breakers can trip many times with not much change but a 480 3 phase breaker is or can be severely damaged with multiple trips causing single phasing because one of the hammer contact sets is usually damaged more than the others but they always open in my experience. If you have a breaker with high resistance on 1 leg with the load off flip the breaker 10-20 times this displaces the carbon and can sometimes give enough time to order a new breaker but I have only found this on 150+ amp breakers, I tried to post this as a comment but it did not work on my phone so had to put it here.