# Electrical circuit breakers, how do I check

Tags: electrical

I had a 15 Amp GFIC/AFIC circuit breaker replaced. Everything is wired correctly. How do I test that the new one is not defective ? Lights still don't work.

Comment: I am not a big fan of some of the new code as the latest GFCI/AFCI breakers that I have worked with are not so good. With that said older equipment may trip a good one.

Comment: How have you confirmed that "everything is wired correctly"?

Answer (score 3):

The only accurate test for a GFCI or AFCI is the built in test button on the breaker/device.

Anything else is convenient, but not completely accurate.

I have a suspicion that the circuit didn't work so you simply replaced the breaker, without troubleshooting to see if that was the actual problem. Most likely you have a problem with the circuit wiring or devices.

Answer (score 0):

How do you test that the new one is not defective? Well, I guess you'd [bolt fault](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84171/how-many-bolted-faults-can-a-residential-circuit-breaker-withstand) it - not that I would nor do I recommend doing that. (of course *I've* never done that to find a CB... :)

How do you check a CB for continuity? Simple: remove it and check it for continuity. I've never had one that would still reset and *not* work.

I'd use a solenoid voltage tester (a Wiggy *not* a V/O meter) to confirm actual potential - with the branch disconnected and the CB powered-up. If test equipment can pop the breaker then it's bad (never had that happen to me) if it doesn't your problem is elsewhere. Which will become obvious when you test the UNLOADED disconnected branch and it shows continuity to ground.